# What does JavaScript do with Number(undefined)?

Tags: javascript, types, undefined, v8, nan

I recently thought about defining a function to copy the functionality of isNaN out of boredom when I found out, that `Number(undefined)` equals `NaN</code>, but if you do`Number(undefined) === NaN`you get`false`.

I even tried `(typeof Number(undefined)) === (typeof NaN)` which returns `true`.

What is JavaScript doing here?

Comment: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/05/the-curious-case-of-javascript-nan.html

Comment: `(NaN == NaN) === false`

Comment: Also, when debugging things like `(typeof Number(undefined)) === (typeof NaN)`, it helps to just log both sides of the `===` separately, you'll see that  both return `"number"`. (Yea, `typeof NaN === "number"`)

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, I knew `typeof NaN === "number"`, but I wasn't aware `NaN` never equals anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant `NaN` is never equal to anything, including `NaN`. The value of `typeof NaN` is "number", because `NaN` is a number constant.

The value of `Number(undefined)` is `NaN`. You can use `isNaN()` to verify that, or simply:

```
var x = Number(undefined);
if (x !== x) alert("It's NaN!");
```

Comment: OP figured out that last line on his own: _"when I found out, that `Number(undefined)` equals `NaN`"_ ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe he'll trust me instead of himself :)

Comment: Good point, some times, an outside _"yeap, that's correct"_ helps!

Comment: Just to add, that although `typeof NaN` is `"number"`, but `NaN instanceof Number` is `false`. JavaScript WAT!

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz that's true, but `17 instanceof Number` is also `false`. Neither `NaN` nor `17` are object instances.

Comment: @Pointy true, but it's counterintuitive anyway :-) normal languages don't mess with types as much as JS does.